# How can i find smallest value in a tree?

Tags: python, tree, find, traversal

```
def Find_Min(tree,smallest):
    if tree == []:  return smallest
    elif tree != []:
        if smallest > tree[0]: smallest = tree[0]
        Find_Min(tree[1],smallest)
        Find_Min(tree[2],smallest)

def main():
    array = [1, [0, [222,[],[]], [4,[],[]] ], [-6, [99,[],[]], []]]
    print("Smallest element in list: " + str(Find_Min(array,array[0])))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

return `None`.

Where am I doing something wrong?
I was expecting `-6`.

Comment: For starters, there's no `return` statement in Find_Min. And function arguments does not work like that: simply put, arguments are "labels" for values, and assigning something to a label does modify not it's previous value - it just attaches a label to new value.

Comment: Just calling a function from within that same function will not pass the return value from the inner call to the outer call; you still have to explicitly return something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This becomes easier when you separate out the visiting of the tree elements from the minimum finding.  It also makes it super easy to create a `find_max` function should you ever need it :-).  Here's some code which should point you in the correct direction ...

```
def visit(tree):
    for elem in tree:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
           for subelem in visit(elem):  # yield_from visit(elem) on python3.3+
               yield subelem
        else:
           yield elem
```

Now finding the minimum is as easy as using the `min` function on the visited elements:

```
def find_min(tree):
    return min(visit(tree))
```

Comment: note that this answer totally changes if your(OP) data structure changes to a binary search tree or any kind of smartly ordered tree,,, this only applies to search spaces that require full exploration (+1 all the same ofc) although I woulda done somethign hacky like `min(literal_eval(re.sub("[^0-9, ]","",str(my_tree))))`

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- Yep.  Basically, I implemented a super simple depth first search algorithm.  If it's a binary search tree then you only need to traverse the tree taking the left branch until you get the bottom (of course, OP's tree is not binary, and it isn't doesn't appear to have any rhyme or reason behind the order of the elements that I can see).  Another data-structure which would really sing here is a heap... find_min would happen in O(1) and the stdlib provides an implementation already (`heapq`)!

Comment: Okey i am understand, but  I have to use my own code.